# Discord.js Command Kick and Ban

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

## Discord.js 12.2.0

Can someone can tell me about of kick and ban commands?

```js
if(message.content === prefix+"ban"){

}


if(message.content === prefix+"kick"){

}
```

Comment: What do you want to know? How to use them or what? Please edit you question and tell us what you want?

Answer (score 2):

You can **ban** or **kick** a member by doing :

```
<GuildMember>.ban() //to ban
```

```
<GuildMember>.kick() //to kick
```

where `<GuildMember>` represents a member of a guild on Discord.

You can get the `<GuildMember>` by doing:

```
message.mentions.members.first();
```

You can refer [how to kick a user](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/faq.html#how-do-i-kick-a-user) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used for my ban and kick commands.
This is my ban command :

```
if (message.content.startsWith("s!ban")) {
    if (!message.guild.member(message.author).hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
            return message.channel.send('You do not have the permission to ban users!');
        }
    if (!message.guild.member(client.user).hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
            return message.channel.send("I don't have the permission to ban users!");
    }
    if (message.mentions.users.size === 0) {
        return message.channel.send("You need to ping a user or the user can't be found!");
    }
    var member = message.mention.members.first();
    member
        .ban()
        .then(member => {
            guild.members.ban(id);
            message.channel.send("*It's a plane* :airplane:, *no its a bird* :bird:, *wait no its just* **" + member.displayName + "** *getting banned :hammer:*");
        })
        .catch(() => {
            message.channel.send("Sorry, you can't ban this member");
        });
    }
```

This is my kick command :

```
if (message.content.startsWith("s!kick")) {
    if (!message.guild.member(message.author).hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) {
        return message.channel.send('You do not have the permission for kick users!');
    }
    if (!message.guild.member(client.user).hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) {
        return message.channel.send("I don’t have the permission for kick users!");
    }
    if (message.mentions.users.size === 0) {
        return message.channel.send("You need to ping a user or the user can't be found!");
    }
    var member = message.mentions.members.first();
    member
        .kick()
        .then(member => {
            message.channel.send(member.displayName + " has been successfully kicked");
        })
        .catch(() => {
            message.channel.send("Sorry, you can't kick this member");
        });
    }
```